# To many re renders TradingView Chart in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tradingview-api

Good day. I have added a Chart to the SPA react app. The Chart is rendered on the page using a user effect. A orderLine also is placed on the chart. There is also an input on the page, and depending on this input, the orderLine should change. However, when the orderLine is drawn, the entire chart will be rendered as a target. Also, when I change the position of the line, I transfer the data to the same input and everything is re-rendered in the same way.

How can I fix this problem and not redraw the chart, but only the orderLine?

```
export const TVChartContainer = ({
                   symbol= 'Binance:BTC/USDT',
                   interval= '1D',
                   containerId = 'tv_chart_container',
                   libraryPath = '/charting_library/',
                   chartsStorageUrl = 'https://saveload.tradingview.com',
                   chartsStorageApiVersion = '1.1',
                   clientId = 'tradingview.com',
                   userId = 'public_user_id',
                   fullscreen = false,
                   autosize = true,
                   studiesOverrides = {},
                   buyLine,
                   setBuyLine,
                 }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const widgetOptions = {
      debug: false,
      symbol: symbol,
      datafeed: Datafeed,
      interval: interval,
      container_id: containerId,
      library_path: libraryPath,
      locale: getLanguageFromURL() || 'en',
      disabled_features: ['use_localstorage_for_settings'],
      enabled_features: ['study_templates'],
      charts_storage_url: chartsStorageUrl,
      charts_storage_api_version: chartsStorageApiVersion,
      client_id: clientId,
      user_id: userId,
      fullscreen: fullscreen,
      autosize: autosize,
      studies_overrides: studiesOverrides,
    };
    const tvWidget = new widget(widgetOptions);

    tvWidget.onChartReady(() => {
      const order = tvWidget.chart().createOrderLine()
        .setText("Buy Line")
        .onMove(function () {
          setBuyLine(order.getPrice().toFixed(2));
        })
        .setLineLength(30)
        .setLineStyle(2)
        .setPrice(buyLine)
        .setLineColor('blue')
        .setQuantity(buyLine);
    })
  }, [symbol, buyLine]);
  return (
    <div
      id={containerId}
      className={'TVChartContainer'}
    />
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `buyLine` in the useEffect, and have it as a dependency, this it will be stuck in an infinite loop. Remove that dependency.

Comment: yes, but if I remove this dependency, the lines will stop being drawn when the data changes

Comment: Why are you passing both the state and the setting of that state from the parent?